# How to Model Date Dimensions with Fact Tables of Different Grains

Tags: data-warehouse

We have some use cases for our DW where we have fact tables at different grains - e.g., sales by store by day (fact 1) and sales budget targets by month (fact 2). They both involve Date as a grain, but in one case the grain is day and the other the grain is period.

Assuming we can't in the near term change the grain, what's the right way to model this?

A Date and a Month dimension, which will have conformed attributes?
1 Date dimension, with nulls or flags or something when it's representing a higher value (e.g., month)
Something else?

Answer (score 3):

You only need one date dimension with one row per day.  Just link to the last day of your period.
E.g. for a monthly aggregated fact just link to the last day of the month in your date dimension.

Comment: Very clever Wouter? How would you identify / manage linking tables with these grains. you'd want to make sure somehow that automatically (a view or stored procedure or something?) drilling across knew about this. Maybe a flag?

Answer (score 0):

Two different dimensions, one for Date and one for Month

Comment: Thanks NickW. How in your example do you make it obvious/easy to the front end that Date and Month are linked? I'd hate to have reporting people need to remember that they need to join these 2 on year/month (or whatever we decide)

Comment: Hi - I'm not sure what you mean by "join these 2"? They are dimensions so you would only be joining them to fact tables and any one fact table would only be joined to one or the other, not both. You'd presumably make it obvious which one is to be joined to by the naming convention you use for the FKs in your fact table e.g. DATE_SK and MONTH_SK

Comment: Hi NickW.Thanks for the answer!

What I meant is
FactTable1 - FK - MonthDim
FactTable2 - FK - DateDim

Lets say that the BI Developer (front end person) needs to link fact table 2 and 1 - a "drill across". I know that you would join MonthDim and DayDim by the fields Year and Date, but I was just wondering if there was a more clever way to do this so we wouldn't have to rely on the front end person having to know the join keys. When you have conformed dimensions (both tables use the SAME dimension) then you don't need to worry about this.

Comment: Hi - you can only drill-across between identical (sets of) keys in 2 tables e.g. you could drill across from customerID in TableA to customerID in TableB. Drilling between the same attribute at different levels of aggregation, such as from month to day,is drilling up (or down)  i.e. it is a hierarchy. How your BI Developer implements hierarchies tends to be very tool specific